# Stack Snippet falha na edição quando usado listas

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Este susposto bug ocorre no momento que clica para editar uma postagem editar ou quando esta criando uma nova pergunta, se adicionar dois *Stack Snippets* dentro de um item de uma lista ocorre isto no "preview" (apenas no "preview"):

> [image: problema]

Mostra algo como:

```
Se usar <img> pode experimentar usar width="", assim:

<pre>4732faf8-d8f5-6b14-ae61-e3eb6fc69236</pre>
```

Um exemplo assim: https://gist.github.com/brcontainer/d488121893e049ef2cd0677254901a2f, copie o conteudo e cole em uma nova pergunta e olhe o "preview"

> Não postei aqui porque o bloco de código não esta aceitando stacksnippet dentro do "Amostra de código"

Comment: Mas também essa lista tá bem confusa. né. Se você colocar um **2.** antes do segundo item (que é o caracteriza a lista) vai funcionar normal.

Comment: @jbueno o item 1 podem conter duas descrições ou 2 códigos.

Comment: Esse código `<pre>blablabla</pre>` troca sempre que faço o teste com o snippet dado. Código esse que não está no texto do post (é algo interno da renderização de snippets que foi cuspido na página). Esta é uma forma bem legal de se mostrar um número aleatório no post!

Answer (score 2):

## Teste do bug

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nunc mi, euismod id dapibus sed, sodales id mi.

   ```html
       teste 1
   ```

   Dois:

   ```html
       teste 2
   ```
2. Aliquam vel libero nulla. In id viverra sem. Curabitur in magna elit. Curabitur tincidunt convallis nisl, sit amet vulputate purus mattis in.

   ```html
       teste 3
   ```

Comment: Na hora que estava escrevendo esta resposta, o bug aconteceu. Quando a resposta foi renderizada, o comportamento foi o esperado. Ao clicar em "editar", o bug volta a acontecer.

Comment: Não é a *única* coisa que fica esquisita na nossa renderização de sublistas, mas já falei com os devs. Valeu pelo exemplo, Victor